# How to link the Assets in WatchKit App to the in InterfaceController class in WatchKit Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, watchkit

I'm very curious about where the xcode links the image files in the assets to the controller classes. I'm using the following code `

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var IV1: WKInterfaceImage!
    @IBOutlet var IV2: WKInterfaceImage!

    var busImages:[String] = ["Bus-48", "Bus-64"]

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    @IBAction func InterchangeImages() {
        busImages.reverse()
        self.IV1.setImageNamed(busImages[0])
        self.IV2.setImageNamed(busImages[1])
    }
}
```

in my project [Project Structure for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTadH.png) and whenever I try to tap on button the images are going blank. I know we can just copy the images to Assets and use setImage(UIImage()) method.

But I'm curious to know how to use the setImage(UIImage()) method without copying the images to assets in the Watchkit extension and directly link the images in assets in Watchkit App. Please let me know about it. Thanks in Advance